# MPI (mpi4py) - irecv() and test() don't work in loop if first test() returned false

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am running several process which communicate asynchronously.

- Process 1 sends a message to process 2 every once in a while.
- Process 2 checks for messages every once in a while.
- If no message is available, process 2 keeps doing other stuff until the next interval.

The problem is: if process 2 starts trying to receive before the process 1 sends anything, all subsequent receives also fail. Inveresely, if process 1 sends any message before process 2 tries to receive, all subsequent receives are successful.

Minimal example using Python and `mpi4py`:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    print("Process 1 started")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(3)

    for i in range(10):
        sys.stdout.flush()

        comm.send(f"Message {i}", dest=1)

        print(f"Process 1 sent message {i}")
        sys.stdout.flush()

        sleep(1)

elif rank == 1:
    print("Process 2 started")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)

    for i in range(1000):
        req = comm.irecv()
        success, message = req.test()
        if success:
            print(f"Process 2 received {message}")
        else:
            print(f"Process 2 didn't receive anything on attempt {i}")
        sys.stdout.flush()

        sleep(3)
```

Gives the following output:

```
Process 1 started
Process 2 started
Process 2 didn't receive anything on attempt 0
Process 1 sent message 0
Process 1 sent message 1
Process 2 didn't receive anything on attempt 1
Process 1 sent message 2
Process 1 sent message 3
Process 2 didn't receive anything on attempt 2
Process 1 sent message 4
Process 1 sent message 5
...
```

Removing the first `sleep` from process 1 results in a successful chain of send/receives:

```
Process 1 started
Process 2 started
Process 1 sent message 0
Process 1 sent message 1
Process 2 received Message 0
Process 1 sent message 2
Process 1 sent message 3
Process 2 received Message 1
Process 1 sent message 4
Process 1 sent message 5
Process 1 sent message 6
Process 2 received Message 2
```

What is missing in my implementation to make the first version work?

Comment: What if you specify `source=0` for `irecv` in receiver?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you repeatedly issue an `Irecv`, but you only keep the last request. So the message can be caught by an early `Irecv`, but you don't have the request for it anymore. You can fix this by doing the `Irecv` just once, and then `Test` in a loop.

However, this runs into a really subtle problem that `Test` is local, and may not force "progress". Both `Probe` and `Iprobe` force the communication to make progress.

So your fix is not really about the difference between `Test` and `Probe`, but you've removed the problem that your initial code issued many receives.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was in using `test()` as a way to check whether there are awaiting incoming messages. The correct way is to use [`probe` or `iprobe`](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Iprobe.html) (not sure what's the actual difference between the two in mpi4py):

Working example after the fix:

```
if rank == 0:
    print("Process 1 started")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(3)

    for i in range(10):
        sys.stdout.flush()

        comm.send(i, dest=1)

        print(f"Process 1 sent message {i}")
        sys.stdout.flush()

        sleep(1)

elif rank == 1:
    print("Process 2 started")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)

    for i in range(1000):
        probe = comm.iprobe()
        if probe:
            message = comm.recv()
            print(f"Process 2 received {message}")
        else:
            print(f"Process 2 didn't receive anything on attempt {i}")
        sys.stdout.flush()

        sleep(3)
```

https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Iprobe.html